# How does VPN secure me from my ISP eavesdropping on me?

Tags: security, vpn, isp

I'm trying to understand the whole VPN thing and how it can protect me, but it still remains very vague to me.

If I connect to a VPN, all data goes through my ISP first, right? What keeps them from trying to decrypt/read the raw data?

Or do you have to run software on your computer to decrypt the incoming information with a personal AES key? That way it would make sense to me

Comment: `What keeps them from trying to decrypt/read the raw data?` - Nothing keeps them from trying.  Really complex math keeps them from succeeding, provided your VPN implements the encryption protocols correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially a VPN is set up between 2 endpoints, in this case your machine and a remote VPN server.

Traffic leaving your machine is encrypted and then sent on to the remote machine where it is decrypted and sent onwards (of course, if you are connecting to an site secured with SSL, that will remain encrypted until it reaches the remote website)

All your ISP can see is the ciphertext.  So in effect, you are running software on your machine that encrypt and decrypt your communications

There's loads more information [here](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/vpn.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading a lot about it, but nowhere was clearly stated that I had to run software on my side to use a VPN. A proxy doesn't require you to and I guess this confused me, although it's two different things

Comment: freek: don't forget to mark the best answer as such to reward those who provided it

Comment: wish I could, but I only joined today and you need 15 rep to vote up..